# Splunk Enterprise SPL search combine multiple field values into 1 field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have the following log line:

```
{"date_time":"20220902-12:20:20.628640865","severity":"INFO","origin":"CME","pipeline":"cme_channel_310","mdflow_core_version":"1.1.0","mdflow_msgapi_version":"2.2.0","mdflow_apps_version":"3.3.0","alias_name":"PROD","num_instruments":"10000"}
```

I want to display (in table format) the origin and versions like so:

```
Origin   Versions
CME      1.1.0/2.2.0/3.3.0
```

I am "close" with using strcat and creating the versionCombo field.  Here is my full query...

```
| spath 
| strcat mdflow_core_version "/" mdflow_msgapi_version "/" mdflow_apps_version versionCombo
| stats values(origin) as Origin values(versionCombo) as Versions
```

The above search results in this with multiple lines of somewhat concatenated strings...

```
Origin   Versions
CME      //
         1.1.0
         1.1.0/2.2.0
         2.2.0/3.3.0
         3.3.0
```

I need it be all on one line with the value: "1.1.0/2.2.0/3.3.0".  Any help here would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Splunk are you using?  Is there anything about the data or the query you haven't shared?  The query works fine on both of my sandbox systems.

[image]

Comment: Version 8.1.4.   That is very interesting.   No, there is nothing else - literally what I posted above is the log line and the spl query.  This is sent through a universal forwarder.  I will post the config of the forwarder.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, if I remove the `| spath`, it works.